# Static Footer View On Android Bottom Sheet

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, bottom-sheet

I am trying to make a **static footer** on a bottomsheet on Android. Below is a GIF of my current attempt. Notice the `footer` text at the bottom of the sheet when it is fully expanded. I want this footer text to **always** show regardless of what state the sheet is in. (e.g. if the sheet is only half expanded, the footer should still show. As the sheet is being expanded/collapsed, the footer should still always show etc.) How can I accomplish this behavior? I have had a look at this: https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel but I would prefer to get a vanilla android solution that does not involve any external libraries.

[image]

Here is my current XML. I think the problem is the footer is anchored to the bottom of the view, but the bottom of the view is only visible if the sheet is fully expanded. I want to see if I can get the footer to show regardless of the state of the sheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:airbnb="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/linear_layout_container">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/header_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:text="Header"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            />

        <com.airbnb.epoxy.EpoxyRecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet_recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            airbnb:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
            android:layout_above="@+id/footer_text"
            android:layout_below="@+id/header_text"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/footer_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:text="Footer"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            airbnb:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here is what my fragment looks like. It is just a blank fragment that shows a bottom sheet:
`ContainerFragment.kt`

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import com.airbnb.epoxy.EpoxyRecyclerView
import com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetDialog

class ContainerFragment : Fragment() {


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.container_fragment_layout, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        view.alpha = 0f
        val bottomSheet = BottomSheetDialog(requireContext())
        val bottomSheetView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.test_bottom_sheet_layout, null)
        bottomSheet.setContentView(bottomSheetView)
        bottomSheet.show()
        val epoxyRecyclerView : EpoxyRecyclerView = bottomSheetView.findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet_recycler_view)
        epoxyRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
        epoxyRecyclerView.withModels {
            (0..100).forEach {
                basicRow {
                    id(it)
                    title("This is the entry at index $it.")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    companion object {
        fun newInstance() = ContainerFragment()
    }
}
```

Here is my fragment layout:
`container_fragment_layout.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: We are facing same ISSUE, did you find any solution?

Comment: We ended up using a `Dialog` instead of bottom sheet. On `Dialog`s it is really easy to keep a static footer. Would really love to know if it is possible on bottom sheets though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to do it programmatically but it's really simpler than it looks. Simply adjust the position of the View as the BottomSheet slides.

1. Add the footer View as a direct child of your BottomSheet

```xml
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#EECCCCCC"
            app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pinned_bottom"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#500000FF"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:text="Bottom" />
    </FrameLayout>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

2. Add a `BottomSheetCallback` and adjust the `translationY` in onSlide()

```kotlin
BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottom_sheet).addBottomSheetCallback(
    object : BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {

        override fun onSlide(bottomSheet: View, slideOffset: Float) {
            val bottomSheetVisibleHeight = bottomSheet.height - bottomSheet.top

            pinned_bottom.translationY =
                (bottomSheetVisibleHeight - pinned_bottom.height).toFloat()
        }

        override fun onStateChanged(bottomSheet: View, newState: Int) {
        }
    })
```

It runs smoothly because you're simply changing the translationY.

You can also use this technique to pin a View in the center of the BottomSheet:

```kotlin
pinned_center.translationY = (bottomSheetVisibleHeight - pinned_center.height) / 2f
```

I've made a sample project on GitHub to reproduce both use cases (pinned to center and bottom): https://github.com/dadouf/BottomSheetGravity

[image: Demo]

Comment: It doesn't work for scrollable content - if you have recyclerview or scrollview inside bottom sheet.

Comment: Have you got any solution for scrollable content? I'm facing same issue

Comment: for scrollable content I used `setY()` instead of `setTranslationY()` and it worked like a charm.

Comment: @МаксимПетлюк The idea is that the pinned views need to be outside of your RecyclerView adapter or ScrollView. For example: make your bottom sheet a FrameView, add both the scrolling container and the pinned view as children.

Comment: @DavidFerrand any possibility to use inside BottomSheetDialogFragment ?

Comment: @Xan I haven't tested but BottomSheetDialogFragment shows a BottomSheetDialog. I see from the [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/bottomsheet/BottomSheetDialog) that BottomSheetDialog has `setContentView` and `getBehavior` so you should be able to follow the same approach as my post: set a custom ViewGroup that includes a footer view, and animate it using a listener on the behavior.

Comment: @DavidFerrand it works but i need to call manually "onSlide" inside oncreate. i don't know why. you do not need it?

Answer (score 4):

@DavidFerrand based using insead `BottomSheetDialogFragment`

```
val behavior: BottomSheetBehavior<*> = (dialog as BottomSheetDialog).behavior
behavior.addBottomSheetCallback(object : BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
    override fun onStateChanged(bottomSheet: View, newState: Int) {}
    override fun onSlide(bottomSheet: View, slideOffset: Float) {
        binding.bottom.y = ((bottomSheet.parent as View).height - bottomSheet.top - binding.bottom.height).toFloat()
    }
}.apply {
    binding.root.post { onSlide(binding.root.parent as View, 0f) }
})
```